# about a web service retrieving data from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, web-services

I am trying to create a web service that can get data from MYSQL database but I have a problem

the web form code

```
namespace John
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.BindGrid();
            }
        }

        private void BindGrid()
        {
           localhost.Service1 service = new localhost.Service1();
            GridView1.DataSource = service.Get(); 
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

and the web service code

```
public DataTable Get()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM nursery1"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            dt.TableName = "nursery1";
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I just follow the steps from this tutorial:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Retrieve-Get-data-from-Database-using-Web-Service-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

or if you have any useful reference about getting data from SQL database using  web service in ASP.NET and C# please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: In private voide BindGrid() there are soap exception was unhandled by user code